# Отслеживание элемента навигации

Tags: html, jquery

Выбираю пункт меню, затем возвращаюсь наверх, на главную - пункт меню остается выделенным. Прошу вас помочь с решением отслеживания пунктов меню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
         <ul class="horizontal-nav trigger-victim">
            <li><a href="#main" class="active go_to">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#catalog" class="go_to">Каталог</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="go_to">О компании</a></li>
            <li><a href="#delievery" class="go_to">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts" class="go_to">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: а что вы конкретно хотите, чтобы когда вы идете на другой пункт, то выделение пропадало?

Comment: Да т.е. иду на пункт "контакты" и выделение у "доставка и оплата" пропадает, а у "контакты" появляется

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('section').each(function(){
       if($(this).offset().top<$(window).scrollTop()+1){
         var currentclass =$(this).attr('id');
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $('a[href="#'+currentclass+'"]').addClass('active');
       }
       
    })
})
```

```css
section{
    height:900px;
}
.active{
    background:red;
}
.horizontal-nav{
position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="horizontal-nav trigger-victim">
            <li><a href="#main" class="active go_to">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#catalog" class="go_to">Каталог</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="go_to">О компании</a></li>
            <li><a href="#delievery" class="go_to">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts" class="go_to">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <section id=main></section>
<section id=catalog></section>
<section id=about></section>
<section id=delievery></section>
<section id=contacts></section>
```